# Garlic + Oil, Why is this recipe safe?

Tags: oil, garlic, pickling, botulism

I've read other questions here and elsewhere that talk about the danger of garlic in oil. I'm trying to figure out why this recipe is safe:

http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/jamie-oliver/amazing-pickled-and-marinated-vegetables-recipe/index.html

The basic recipe calls for a pickling liquid of vinegar, water and salt. The vegetables are boiled for three minutes and then scooped out and placed in a pickling marinade of oil, sliced raw garlic and a chili. The vegetables and marinade (but not the vinegar solution) are placed in jars and stored for up to three months.

As far as I can tell shouldn't this recipe be at a high risk for botulism contamination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REDACTED. *Botulism growth is inhibited at pH of 4.6 or lower. The pH of this recipe is lower than 4.6 because of the vinegars.
http://www.ext.colostate.edu/pubs/foodnut/09305.html*

After re-reading the recipe, I think the OP is right. This is not the safest recipe out there.

For a great pickling recipe that is safe, try this: http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/pickled-beets-recipe/index.html

Comment: Is enough vinegar actually added to the oil to change the ph?  The vegetables are boiled in the vinegar and then drained.  The vegetables are then added to the garlic/oil marinade.  The bulk of the vinegar is discarded.

Comment: After re-reading the recipe, I think you're right. This isn't the safest recipe. The boiling in an acidic liquid (both the heat and acidity) will kill C. botulinum, but not the spores, which can regenerate.